# Removing sensitive data from Git. "fatal: ambiguous argument 'rm'"

Tags: linux, git, ambiguous-grammar

I'm trying to run this command:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename.js' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'rm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree
.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: This might be better addressed at the Server Fault site

Comment: From Windows CMD, use doble quotes " instead of single '

Comment: Executing from Git Bash worked for me

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It depends on the shell you are using.
On Windows, with msysgit for instance, see [issue 477](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=477#c12):

> Single quotes do not have a special meaning with CMD. Do not expect that they work 
>   the same as with a POSIX shell. Call filter-branch like this:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter "GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=void GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=void GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=just.a.test@kernel.org GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=just.a.test@kernel.org; git commit-tree \"$@\"" HEAD
```

Multiple lines:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter "GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=void \
                                   GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=void \
                                   GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=just.a.test@kernel.org \
                                   GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=just.a.test@kernel.org; \
                                   git commit-tree \"$@\"" HEAD
```

As mentioned in "[How to pass a programmatically generated list of files to `git filter-branch`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19507601/6309)"

> Each argument to the various `...-filters` needs to be a single string. That string is saved as a shell variable.

So make sure `'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename.js'` is considered a string in the shell you are in.
As [Constantine Ketskalo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7402089/constantine-ketskalo) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394563/removing-sensitive-data-from-git-fatal-ambiguous-argument-rm/21399771#comment99357419_21399771):

> Windows 10, PyCharm, GitPython, same command as in question.
>   Simply changed `'` to `"` inside the string and it worked!

Comment: I tried doing this call twice (using the corrected format), only to get on the second time the following:  `Cannot create a new backup.
A previous backup already exists in refs/original/
Force overwriting the backup with -f
rm: cannot remove '/YOURPATH/.git-rewrite/backup-refs': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory '/YOURPATH/.git-rewrite': Directory not empty`.

Comment: @drzaus yes, you might have to remove manually the `/YOURPATH/.git-rewrite` folder.

Comment: `So make sure 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename.js' is considered a string in the shell you are in.` VonC, thank you so much. It saved me who knows how much more time it could be. Windows 10, PyCharm, GitPython, same command as in question. Simply changed `'` to `"` inside the string and it worked!

Comment: @ConstantineKetskalo Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

On windows, you have to use double quote `"` instead of single `'`