# Removing large files(with spaces in file name) that are cached in git

Tags: git, github

While trying to commit changes in git, I get the following error

```
remote: error: File folder/Unconfirmed 866711.crdownload is 486.30 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected
![remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

So, I tried removing the cached file using the command given [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history)

```
git rm --cached "Unconfirmed 866711.crdownload"
```

also,

```
git rm --cached "Unconfirmed\ 866711.crdownload"
```

But, it doesn't work

```
fatal: pathspec 'Unconfirmed\ 866711.crdownload' did not match any files
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?
EDIT: 
Following the suggestions below, I tried

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch folder/Unconfirmed 866711.crdownload" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

I get the following,

```
Rewrite 493310fe1e5fd4f06c9ee30b5b5157baae05358b (265/266) (181 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' was rewritten
WARNING: Ref 'refs/stash' is unchanged
```

Following git filter, I deleted the large file from the folder and did

```
git push origin --force --all
```

This results in the same error

```
remote: error: File folder/Unconfirmed 866711.crdownload is 486.30 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: @phd I tried `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f folder/Unconfirmed 866711.crdownload' HEAD` suggested in one of the posts in the links that you share. Unfortunately, I get  `fatal: ambiguous argument 'folder/Unconfirmed': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'` . Probably because of the space in the file name the path to file appears to be broken. Any suggestions on how to track paths of file names with spaces?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394563/removing-sensitive-data-from-git-fatal-ambiguous-argument-rm helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter-branch with a filename in the space using an escape character.
So if your large file is called `huge file.zip`, your commands will be:

```sh
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf huge\ file.zip' HEAD
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to follow the question and seem like it is because of a large file.

I have followed an article on medium, hopefully, it can be of help.

Please find https://medium.com/@marcosantonocito/fixing-the-gh001-large-files-detected-you-may-want-to-try-git-large-file-storage-43336b983272 as the link for same.

As per my understanding, this is happening since file is tracked now and command which can be of help is: 
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch fixtures/11_user_answer.json'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394563/removing-sensitive-data-from-git-fatal-ambiguous-argument-rm helped

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error. Please see the updates in my original post. Note: I'm using git on Windows