# Removing large files from git

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

This is a follow up to my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355707/removing-large-fileswith-spaces-in-file-name-that-are-cached-in-git?noredirect=1#comment104907356_59355707).
I'm trying to remove a large file that I committed to git. Based on the suggestion given in my previous post, I tried

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch folder/Unconfirmed 866711.crdownload" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Following the above command, I tried to push all the changes

```
git push origin --force --all
```

However, I got the same error that was displayed before using `filter-branch`

```
remote: error: File folder/Unconfirmed 866711.crdownload is 486.30 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Alternatively, I also tried

```
git add --all

git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch folder/Unconfirmed 866711.crdownload" HEAD
```

But, I get the following

```
Cannot rewrite branches: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
```

I'm not sure if I have missed any command or flags. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot rewrite branches: Your index contains uncommitted changes.

You have uncommitted changes in your working directory i.e changes staged for a commit (check `git status` output) . Either commit those changes if you wish to or preserve those uncommitted changes by using [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_name) and [apply](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-apply--index-q--quietltstashgt) them once you have executed the `filter-branch` command.

If you don't want the uncommitted changes, then you can perform a hard reset.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

---

As [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) mentioned in the comment below and as per GitHub help [page](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#using-filter-branch), it is not recommended to use `stash` before `filter-branch`

> Warning: If you run git filter-branch after stashing changes, you
>   won't be able to retrieve your changes with other stash commands.
>   Before running git filter-branch, we recommend unstashing any changes
>   you've made.

So instead commit the changes if you want to preserve the uncommitted changes. Then proceed with the `filter-branch` command.

---

Your `filter-branch` command, is missing single quotes (to account for the space in the name of the file to be deleted)

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch 'folder/Unconfirmed 866711.crdownload'" HEAD
```

Comment: I recommend *not* using `git stash` with `git filter-branch`. The filter-branch command can operate on all refs, including the stash ref, and can destroy stashes in the process.

Comment: @torek, is it possible to exclude stash ref  from being overwritten in `filter-branch` ?

Comment: Yes: if you specify a list of refs to rewrite (e.g., `git filter-branch <filter info> -- branchA branchB`) it rewrites only those branches. But I think it is easier and more practical to just commit, then filter, then back out the last commit.

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari  As you suggested, I committed all the changes  followed by filter-branch. I get the following, `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/stash' is unchanged` . Could you please suggest what should be the next step? Can I push the changes to the repository?

Comment: @Natasha, The warning suggests that your command didn't change any refs i.e it wasn't successful.

Comment: @Natasha, Have you followed [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#using-filter-branch) ?

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari Thanks a ton! I think it worked this time with the single quotes, "Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
Ref 'refs/stash' was rewritten" . I get one warning now. can I go ahead and push the changes  after adding the path of the large file to .gitignore and commiting the change?

Comment: @Natasha, yes, you can do that, The warning suggests that other than `refs/heads/master` all other refs remain unchanged

Comment: Just ran `git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch 'public/long file name.webarchive'" HEAD` and got back `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/35-create-shippet-in-new' is unchanged`. Do I need to do something else?Trying to get rid of large files I inadvertently added years ago.